# File password protection for one time use

Tags: password-protection

Need to lock a file for a single time. As in when the password is entered the file opens up and never asks for the password again. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Can the file be accessible multiple times, though? If so, I would go for a password protected zipfile. The user needs to extract it using a password, and after that, the file can be used without a password.

Comment: Cant use the Zip folder. Will unnecessarily increase my users work and hamper his experience.

Comment: That answer makes this question unnecessary complicated. What about a self-extracting executable that is password protected?